# Json being returned incorrectly from JsonConverter

Tags: c#, json, web-services, json.net, jsonserializer

I need to create some JSON in C#, with the following format:

```
{
    "id": 10,
    "items": [
        {
            "text": "Link 1",
            "attr": { "href": "/somepage" },
            "menuId": 20
        },
         {
            "text": "Link 1",
            "attr": { "href": "/someotherpage", "class": "test" },
            "menuId": 21
        }
    ]
}
```

I've created a web service to create the string based on a series of objects. First of all, my objects:

```
public class MenuItems
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

And:

```
public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {
        this.Attr = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    }

    public string Text { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> Attr { get; set; }
    public string MenuId { get; set; }
}
```

To get the property names in lowercase I have a simple contract resolver:

```
public class LowercaseContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(string propertyName)
    {
        return propertyName.ToLower();
    }
}
```

And then, my code to build my objects:

```
var list = new List<MenuItem>();

var children = //a call to our CMS api
foreach (var child in children)
{
    var menuItem = new MenuItem();
    menuItem.Text = child.PageName;
    menuItem.MenuId = child.ContentLink.ID.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    menuItem.Attr.Add("href", urlResolver.GetUrl(child.ContentLink));
    menuItem.Attr.Add("data-id-test", "Dave");
    list.Add(menuItem);
}

var obj = new MenuItems {Id = id, Items = list};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj,
    new JsonSerializerSettings() {ContractResolver = new LowercaseContractResolver()});

return json;
```

The JSON that's being returned looks like:

> "{\"id\":\"69\",\"items\":[{\"text\":\"Listing Media\",\"attr\":{\"href\":\"/pages-for-testing/news-and-media/listing-media/\",\"data-id-test\":\"Dave\"},\"menuid\":\"179\"},{\"text\":\"Listing Page Dates\",\"attr\":{\"href\":\"/pages-for-testing/news-and-media/listing-page-dates/\",\"data-id-test\":\"Dave\"},\"menuid\":\"176\"},{\"text\":\"Listing Child Page\",\"attr\":{\"href\":\"/pages-for-testing/news-and-media/listing-child-page/\",\"data-id-test\":\"Dave\"},\"menuid\":\"173\"},{\"text\":\"Press Releases\",\"attr\":{\"href\":\"/pages-for-testing/news-and-media/press-releases/\",\"data-id-test\":\"Dave\"},\"menuid\":\"70\"}]}"

Which is not being read as valid JSON, but im really not sure why. My contract is decorated with the JSON response format e.g.:

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "json/{id}")]
    string DoWork(string id);
```

If I paste that JSON response into http://codebeautify.org/view/jsonviewer, it states that the entire string is just an array. Firefix tells me it's an array of individual characters, so there's clearly something I'm doing wrong.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Change your method `DoWork` so that it returns `MenuItem` and don't serialize the object manually, just return it in your method. WCF will do all serialization/deserialization for you.

Comment: Wow - that's simple, except, I need the properties in lowercase...any way of doing that without the JsonConverter?

Comment: You can use `DataContract` and `DataMember` attributes...

Comment: Hi @L.B how do I accept a comment as the rigth answer? Your comments solved our issue perfectly.